# Did Cartman truly change during season 20?

Tags: character, analysis, south-park

Season 20 took most by surprise by having the most sociopathic and sadistic character in all of South Park attempt to change his ways.
But did he really? 
The first episode shows Cartman teasing the girls by insincerely praising women for being hilarious, mocking them all the while. 
He reads a rebooted version of Red Riding Hood- now called "Little Red Riding Kyle", bashing his arch rival.

Any answers? Because I really doubt Cartman of all people would genuinely turn over a leaf that quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartman himself never actually changed, persay. He's still the sadistic pyschopath he always used to be.

The only difference now, besides the changing in humour style of the show makers and what is tolerable by the ever changing political correctness culture of the viewership (of which the show spends a great deal of time parodying.), is that Cartman has simply changed his method of parodying.

It's no longer funny to have the character murder and feed the parents to his rival (Scott Tennerman). But it's funny to make fun of gender politics and SJWs

On top of that, the kids themselves should reflect actual children. People who have no real concept of what reality is compared to their imagination, no concrete moral standing ground and constantly changing attention spans of what's cool.